# ListView show only n rows

Tags: android

Is there any way to show certain amount of rows < total amount. I've achieved it by simple putting appropriate height dp value to my listview element, but I wonder whether there's a native/smarter way.

Comment: Why you want to show certain amount of rows? If so don't insert in the listView if you don't want to show it..

Comment: I would think if you override the getCount() method of your adapter to return a value that the ListView won't show more items than whatever value you return.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit number of rows of listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540350/limit-number-of-rows-of-listview)