# Sizing a ListView when it's a nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-nested-fragment

I want a ListView to fill the space available to it while still leaving room for a small footer view at the bottom of the screen. I'm trying to use a RelativeLayout to accomplish this and attempted to use the solution discussed at [Limit number of rows of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540350/limit-number-of-rows-of-listview) . The problem I'm running into is I'm using nested Fragments, so my ListView is actually a FrameLayout in my xml then I load a ListFragment into that frame dynamically. Given the nested fragment stipulation, how can I get my FrameLayout to "stackFromBottom" as I would with a ListView? I just need to stop the list from pushing the other View off the bottom of the screen. Thanks for your time all.

Comment: **The problem I'm running into is I'm using nested Fragments** RUN AWAY

Comment: It has been more challenging than I anticipated, but so far I've been able to solve all of the problems it's caused. If they want everyone to Fragment All The Things, they definitely need to make the nested Fragments less painful to work with.

Comment: The `FrameLayout` is the container for the `ListFragment`(containing the `ListView`)? If yes, I don't see where do you have problems, you could just add the footer at the bottom of the Relativelayout and then place the `FrameLayout` between the top and that bottom view.

Comment: I thought that would work as well, but what's happening is for a moment that view takes up the entire bottom of the screen (its space plus the ListView's space), then when the activity loads my ListFragment into the FrameLayout it takes over that entire space and pushed the bottom view right off the screen.

Comment: You should post some code, especially the layout files you use in the app.

Comment: Lukesprog was correct, I just needed to modify my code a tiny bit and that got it working. Thank you much! Edit: I'm a new user here, would it be more appropriate to delete this question or leave it as is in case it helps someone else later? It seems my problem was a minor misunderstanding, so I'm not sure how useful this thread would be for future users?

Comment: If you solved the problem post an answer(with the solution or an explanation at least) and accept it(check the mark near the answer). Don't delete questions, too many deleted questions(or/and downvoted ones) and you risk a question ban. Pro tip for the future, when commenting use the `@username` notation so that user gets a notification about your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/advertisement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Ads will appear here"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/news_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/carousel_menu"
    android:layout_above="@id/advertisement"/>
```

The trick was to set both layout_above AND layout_below for the FrameLayout, I had only been setting one and that was apparently allowing the layout to push it off of the screen. Also worth noting is they had to be declared in reverse order of how they actually appear on the page, so that the FrameLayout could properly reference the other View.